# How can I use the RowDataBound declaration on a GridView to navigate away to new .aspx page with Specific window size

Tags: asp.net, gridview, new-window, rowdatabound

I used the following code in rowdatabound event

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
 e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format("window.location = 'CandidateProfile.aspx?candidateID={0}';", DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "candidateID"))

}
```

I want to change it so the click event opens in a new window with specified height and width

how can I do that , plz help

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you can apply `window.open(url)` and there you can set some parameters to control that window.